# 500 - Internal server error when publish asp.net web App on network solution plesk

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, web-hosting, plesk

I'm uploaded all files of asp.net project to plesk of www.networksolutions.com and when open url in the web browser this message will appear

"500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

how i can solve the problem
Note : i'm trying to edit web.config but this is not useful

this is my web.config

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ContestConn" connectionString="****" />
</connectionStrings>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
     PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies> 
    </compilation>


    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>

    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <defaultDocument>
    <files>
    <add value="index.aspx" />
    </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried publishing your application and then deploy the published files on the server? Also, ensure database connectionstring is correct.

Answer (score 1):

2 things that you can do here.

1. Check event logs during the time of issue. If its an application issue, the exception will be listed here.
2. Enable Freb logs for the website and 500 status code. You can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr) article to enable FREB

Please share results from FREB logs here. I can provide more insights based on what FREB captures.